# JS Formatar diferença entre duas datas e exibir resultado formatado por extenso em anos meses e dias

Tags: javascript, react, data, formatação, momentjs

Preciso de uma função em javascript que receba uma data no formato UTC (como "2022-05-31T14:48:35.4766667" por exemplo) e retorne a diferença entre hoje e essa data por exenso no formato ano, meses, dias.

Exemplos considerando que **"hoje"** é dia **03/06/2022**

1. Exemplo 1

   - entrada: "2022-05-31T14:48:35.4766667"
   - saída: *3 dias*
2. Exemplo 2

   - entrada: "2022-01-31T14:48:35.4766667"
   - saída: *4 meses e 3 dias*
3. Exemplo 3

   - entrada: "2021-01-21T14:48:35.4766667"
   - saída: *1 ano, 4 meses e 13 dias*

##### Código que tentei fazer: https://pastebin.com/cvZ6hREn

##### Entradas que não funcionam neste código:

1. "2022-05-23T18:36:10.1733333" (retorna um mês a mais)
2. "2022-05-31T14:48:35.4766667" (retorna um mês a mais)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Link com func para calcular diferença em dias entre duas datas: [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Código q fiz q resolveu a situação: https://pastebin.com/hFt4Hwu5;
Para que a saída fique idêntica à descrição da pergunta, é necessário fazer uma tratativa na hora de montar a string de retorno...

Provavelmente este código não funcione 100% caso o intervalo passe por algum ano bissexto, porém para minha situação eu preciso exibir uma data "aproximada", e portanto o código feito anteriormente atende aos requisitos...

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sugestão: leia ["*Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?*"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/112052) (apesar de ter algum texto, toda a parte importante da sua resposta está nos links, então é basicamente uma resposta que só tem links). Se for o caso, daria até pra traduzir/adaptar a resposta do SO, basta seguir [estas orientações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7678/112052), além de trazer o código do pastebin pra cá (ou se for muito grande, colocar uma versão mais enxuta)